# How can I get the value of a src from a string variable

Tags: c#, string

I have a string value that will have following declared value:

```
<img alt="Desert.jpg" src="/PublishingImages/Lists/Images/NewForm/Desert.jpg" width="174" style="BORDER: 0px solid; ">
```

The value will have different src value. what I would like to do is to grab the value inside src. I was thinkin of using substring but since the value inside src can varie I dont know how to accomplish this.

This is what I need `/PublishingImages/Lists/Images/NewForm/Desert.jpg`

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like XML, so use an XML parser?

Comment: Yeah its data from a datatable class

Answer (score 2):

Use something like `Regex.Match(yourString, "src=.*?\"")` then do a substring from 5th character and remove the last quote. Regex might not be correct. You should get the idea.

Comment: This is not a regex that matches a valid html attribute

Comment: Your string will be most probably encoded. You need to take care of that.

Comment: My goal was to say that regex can be used here. I know there is one src and two double quotes. My regex is obviously not correct as i have accepted in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse HTML:

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"PathToFile"); // or use doc.LoadHtml to get it from a string
var imgHrefSrc = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img").Attributes["src"];
string value = imgHrefSrc.Value; // /PublishingImages/Lists/Images/NewForm/Desert.jpg
```

[How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for parsing HTML (available from NuGet):

```
string html = "<img alt=\"Desert.jpg\" src=\"/PublishingImages/Lists/Images/NewForm/Desert.jpg\" width=\"174\" style=\"BORDER: 0px solid; \">";
var img = HtmlNode.CreateNode(html);
var src = img.Attributes["src"].Value;
```

Result:

```
"/PublishingImages/Lists/Images/NewForm/Desert.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you want the answer in c# but here is a java code that parses your string and writes url into console:

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
       String x= "<img alt=\"Desert.jpg\" src=\"/PublishingImages/Lists/Images/NewForm/Desert.jpg\" width=\"174\" style=\"BORDER: 0px solid; \">";
       String a=x.split(" ")[2].split("\"")[1];

           System.out.println(a);

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex as the simplest solution that doesn't require additional libraries you may or may not need otherwise:

```
Regex rx = new Regex("src\\s?=\\s?\"[^\"]*\"");
string x = "<img alt=\"Desert.jpg\" src=\"/PublishingImages/Lists/Images/NewForm/Desert.jpg\" width=\"174\" style=\"BORDER: 0px solid; \">";

Console.WriteLine(rx.IsMatch(x));
```

Note that this regex allows for whitespace between 'src', '=' and the quoted value and looks for both the opening and closing quote.

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex as a lightweight solution.

Try this regex (tested on http://regexpal.com/):

```
src=\"([^\"]*)\"
```

And you could extract the string using captured group

Sample code:

```
string input = "<img alt=\"Desert.jpg\" src=\"/PublishingImages/Lists/Images/NewForm/Desert.jpg\" width=\"174\" style=\"BORDER: 0px solid; \">";
string pattern = "src=\"([^\"]*)\"";
string extractedString = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Groups[1].Value;
```